# What is more effective way to get an element by id - #id or span#id and why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

What is more effective way to get an element by id (if its id is unique)?

```
#id
```

or

```
#div1 #id
```

or

```
span#id
```

and why?

Could you please tell me where I can read about such things?
(How to use jQuery selectors faster and more effectively and **why exactly so**)

Thank you!

Comment: Those selectors are not equivalent so it's pointless to discuss which one is *more effective* unless we can see the HTML.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556737/jquery-selectors-speed

Comment: the most effective way is not to use jquery to fetch an id

Comment: @Ibu I just don't understand the hate some developers have for jQuery. If something makes my code faster to write and more compatible with multiple browsers, why shouldn't I use it? Complaining about jQuery sounds like bicyclists complaining about cars -- just because your approach is efficient doesn't mean it's the best.

Comment: Wow easy there @mblase75, nothing against jquery, its my fav library, the OP asked what is the most efficient way to fetch the ID and doing a simple getElementById is the most efficient way. jquery selector has to parse the string first to know what you are trying to do. you are not limited to use only jQuery you know, so a good combination is always the best choice

Comment: @Ibu My apologies -- I guess that comment was really meant for someone else. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#id` // most efficient way to get an element by Id in jQuery

id's of HTML elements are suppose to be unique and because of this jQuery will make use of `document.getElementById()` instead of `document.getElementsByTagName()` and iterate though the array of elements searching for the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

```
#id
```

Why? Because it doesn't look on another conditions, and in any case, `#id` should be only one so it doesn't make (in a lot of cases) sense to use `span#id`

Answer (score 1):

Just the id is better simply because the code have to look for a single element.

See this test that proove it http://jsperf.com/id-vs-tag-id

Answer (score 1):

CSS selectors (aswell as *Sizzle*, the thing within jQuery which does the query job) work from

**right to left**

knowing that, you can easily answer the question yourself. Just querying for `#id` is always the fastest solution. Not only for the reason that more statements after that would be queried first, but also jQuery optimizes this case away for you. That means, just having a selector like `#id` would directly invoke `.getElementById()`, which is just the fastest possible DOM operation to get a reference to an element.

However, it's also faster not to be overexplicit in other cases. Thats because of the *right to left* thing.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery its very easy to just use `$("#theId")` cause all its looking for is the unique id rather than looking for other conditions such as a parent id

Answer (score 0):

`#id` is the fastest, because it is unique.

I don't know where you can read up on this, but here is a page where you can test and benchmark selectors:

[Benchmark selectors](http://projets.geekfg.net/?/7-jquery-expressions-benchmarkr.htm)